# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos x \cos{(A \cos x)}}{B \cos x +C \sin x}\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos x \cos{(A \cos x)}}{B \cos x+C \sin x}\,dx$$

Is it possible to calculate this? (A, B, C are assumed to be real numbers.)

I would be grateful if you could share some of the good integration skills, references, or any advice.

Comment: Where did you get this integral from/do you think there is a closed form?

Comment: For $C=0$, there is a solution as well as for $A=0$.

Comment: @Ty. Actually, I got this in the process of solving a physics problem, so I wanna believe that there is a closed form.

Comment: Yeah I am fairly sure that there is not a closed form expression.  Are there specific cases of A, B, and C that you're interested in?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yup, thank you!!! (succeded)

Comment: @Ty. Really...?! At first, I thought it would appear as a combination of special functions, such as the Bessel function. (I'm interested in the general case.)

Comment: If $A\ll 1$, there is a solution as an infinite series.